# Use of Undeclared Identifier 'UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification'

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, identifier

I'm working on implementing notifications for the first time. I'm having issues at this line:

```
[noteCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeChangedSignificantly:)
                           name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
```

From this code:

```
if (self)
    {
        _stepCounter = [[CMStepCounter alloc] init];
        self.stepsToday = -1;

        NSNotificationCenter *noteCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

        // subscribe to relevant notifications
        [noteCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeChangedSignificantly:)
                           name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
        [noteCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterForeground:)
                           name:NSExtensionHostWillEnterForegroundNotification
                         object:nil];
        [noteCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(didEnterBackground:)
                           name:NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                         object:nil];

        _stepQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        _stepQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

        // start counting
        [self _updateStepsTodayFromHistoryLive:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Removed thanks message.

Comment: Did you import UIKit?

Comment: Please mention what isn't working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Your use of NSExtensionHostWillEnterForegroundNotification suggests that this code is supposed to be running in an app extension (something that you mysteriously neglected to mention in your question).

Well, an extension has no access to UIApplication - or its notifications. See the section in Apple's docs called "Some APIs Are Unavailable to App Extensions":

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are using the same source code as I am for pedometer access. Here is what I had to do to fix error.

Add link to Pedometer-Prefix.pch under...

App Target > Build settings > Apple LLVM 7.0 - Language > Prefix Header

(Mine) example:

"App Name"/Other/Pedometer-Prefix.pch

Pedometer-Prefix.pch below

```
//
//  Prefix header
//
//  The contents of this file are implicitly included at the beginning of every source file.
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_7_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 7.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
#endif
```

Also make sure you add the libraries in code above.